# Android Authenticator Launch Login Screen When No Account Present

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, android-authenticator

I've built an Authenticator, I've built a SyncAdapter (both can be manually executed through the settings on the emulator).

How do I get my application to launch the login screen (addAccount method) when the app launches, if no account is found?

Here is my Manifest.xml...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lateral.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".myappApplication">
        <activity android:name=".ui.EventListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".authenticator.AccountAuthenticatorService" android:exported="true" android:process=":auth">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator"/>
        </service>

        <service android:name="sync.EventsSyncAdapterService" android:exported="true" android:process=":events">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/sync_events" />
        </service>

        <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:name=".authenticator.myappAuthenticatorActivity">
            <!--
                No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
                someone who explicitly knows the class name
            -->
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't going through the `AccountManager` work? Something like:

```
 AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
 Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("myCustomAccount");
 if (accounts.length == 0) {
    accountManager.addAccount("myCustomAccount", null, null, null, this,
                               null, null);
  }
```

Comment: In your app :) Call it from `onResume()` to handle the case when the user deletes the account and then goes back to your app.

Comment: Perfect -- as mentioned by @zed-scio how do I prevent the other intent from displaying before the login screen is shown.. at this point the onResume method only includes your code and 'super.onResume();' but the intent that is set to show as default flashes up

Comment: You might want to make it a bit more user friendly than that: show some sort of UI, saying 'you don't have an account, do you want to register one?' Let the user choose, don't just force it on them.

Comment: but.. they have to have an account.. how else will they get data from my web service?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12418/discussion-between-rabbott-and-nikolay-elenkov)

Answer (score 1):

In your 'EventListActivity' onCreate, check to see if there are any accounts. If there aren't, open the Authenticator activity. If you want to make it do the check and show Authenticator, before EventListActivity's UI shows, all you have to do is add the code before 'setContentView' in the onCreate method.

Comment: So this isnt something that happens, I have do this manually and launch the intent? I figured android would pick this up and launch if nothing is detected..

Comment: I figured you were saying that you made your own AccountManager class. If that isn't the case. Use below

Answer (score 0):

Check if account exists,if not go to login screen.

```
public static boolean accountExists(Context ctx, AccountManager accountManager) {
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(
  ctx.getString(R.string.account_type)
);
return accounts.length > 0;
}
```